# Cycles: Displacement suddenly stretched

Tags: cycles-render-engine

After applying vertex paint to my object the displacement is somehow stretched. I dont know if this is really the reason though. Because it is still stretched when i remove the vertex colors. Does anyone have an idea how i can fix this?

The displacement is achieved with a noise node on the displacement value of the material, nothing fancy.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can we see a node setup or a .blend, please?

Comment: Maybe double check the mapping, sometimes it gets mussed up.

Comment: Is it possible that you have touched the scaling?  Press CTRL+A and choose scale to reset the scale. That may help.